# What does it mean to eliminate $\theta$ from these equations? How should I do it?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Eliminate $\theta$ from the following pairs of equations:
>
> A) $x=\sin \theta$, $y=\sin 2\theta$
>
> B) $x=3\cos 2\theta +1$, $y=2\sin \theta$

My problem is I really don't understand what the question is asking? The answer in the book seems like it is asking me to put everything in terms of $x$ and $y$? And if it is, how do I go about that?
Thank you!

EDIT: My attempt:

$$y = 2\sin \theta \cos \theta $$
$${y \over {2\sin \theta }} = \cos \theta $$
so as $$x = \sin \theta $$
$$\cos \theta  = {y \over {2x}}$$
what do i do from here?

Comment: If you know $x(\theta)$ and $y(\theta)$, it asks for $y(x)$.

Comment: Hint for #1: rewrite $\sin2\theta=2\sin\theta\cos\theta$ and $\cos\theta=\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}$. Can we get rid of $\theta$ now?

Comment: Find an algebraic identity involving $x,y$ but no $\theta$.

Comment: For #2, remember that $\cos(2\theta)=1-2\sin^2(\theta)$.

Comment: You are almost there. Just remember that $\sin^2(\theta)+\cos^2(\theta)=1$

Comment: @IanMateus could you explain why I would need to remember the pythagorean identity?

Comment: The purpose here is to relate $y$ and $x$ somehow. You don't *need* it, it is just the clearer way I saw to relate them without any $\theta$s messing around. This implies $x^2 + \left(\frac{y}{2x}\right)^2=1$, quite convenient.

Comment: @IanMateus nice :-)

Comment: this is called polar form (given eqn).when we convert it into one eqn that is called cartesian form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've done the hard part. Of A):

> $$
> \begin{align} 
> \sin\theta & = x \\ \\
> \cos\theta  & = {\frac y{2x}}
> \end{align}$$

This is where the Pythagorean Identity (as you call it) comes in very handy, indeed:

$$\quad\quad\quad\sin^2(\theta) + \cos^2(\theta) = 1$$

$$\iff \left(\sin\theta \right)^2 + \left(\cos\theta \right)^2 = 1$$

$$x^2 + \left(\dfrac{y}{2x}\right)^2 = 1$$

Then just simplify!

---

Part B:

> $$x = 3 \cos 2\theta, \quad x = 2\sin \theta$$

$$x = 3(1-2\sin^2\theta) \tag{$\cos(2\theta) = 1 - 2\sin^2\theta$}$$ 
$$x= \frac 32(2 - (1 - \cos^2\theta)) \tag{$\sin^2\theta = 1 - \cos^2 \theta$}$$ 
$$x = \frac 32 (\cos^2 \theta + 1) \iff \frac 23 x - 1 = \cos^2\theta$$
$$ $$
$$ y = 2 \sin \theta \iff \sin \theta = y/2$$
$$ $$
$$\sin^2 \theta + \cos ^2 \theta = 1\tag{Pythagorean identity again}$$
$$\left(\frac y2\right)^2 + \left(\frac 23 x - 1\right) = 1$$

Simplify.

Comment: Nice Amyyyyyyy ++

Comment: @Ross Thanks, yes, typo I'm guessing. I had it correct at the end of the post! (Typos can be embarrassing.)

Answer (score -2):

A) $y = \sin 2\theta$, $y = 2\sin\theta\cos\theta$, $y = 2x\sqrt{1-x^2}$
B) Similarly you will find the answer as $3-3y^2+1$